# request body schema missing properties / why am I getting an incomplete schema model

Tags: typescript, swagger, openapi, loopback, loopback4

Could someone help me understand how models in loopback4 work?
I defined a model that looks like this:

```
@model()
export class ProductViewConfig extends BaseConfig {
  @property({
    type: 'string',
    id: true,
    generated: true,
  })
  _id?: string;


  @property({
    type: 'array',
    itemType: 'object',
  })
  tiles: Array<TileOptions>;


  constructor(data?: Partial<ProductViewConfig>) {
    super(data);
  }
}

export interface ProductViewConfigRelations {
  // describe navigational properties here
}

export type ProductViewConfigWithRelations = ProductViewConfig & ProductViewConfigRelations;
```

the baseConfig class that it extends from looks like this:

```
@model({
  settings: {
    strict: true
  }
})
export class BaseConfig extends Entity {
  @property({
    type: 'object',
    required: true,
  })
  configMetadata: ConfigMetadata;

  @property({
    type: 'array',
    itemType: 'object',
  })
  sharedUsers: Array<SharedUsers>;

  @property({
    type: 'array',
    itemType: 'object',
  })
  sharedRoles: Array<SharedRoles>;

  constructor(data?: Partial<BaseConfig>) {
    super(data);
  }
}

export interface BaseConfigRelations {

  // describe navigational properties here
}

export type BaseConfigWithRelations = BaseConfig & BaseConfigRelations;
```

and My ConfigMetadata Model looks like this:

```
@model({ settings: { strict: true } })
export class ConfigMetadata extends Entity {
  @property({
    type: 'string',
    required: true,
  })
  name: string;

  @property({
    type: 'string',
    required: true,
  })
  description: string;

  @property({
    type: 'date',
    required: true,
  })
  dateCreated: string;

  @property({
    type: 'date',
    required: true,
  })
  lastUpdatedOn: string;

  @property({
    type: 'string',
    required: true,
  })
  creatorId: string;

  @property({
    type: 'string',
    required: true,
  })
  creatorName: string;


  constructor(data?: Partial<ConfigMetadata>) {
    super(data);
  }
}

....
```

And I have a post endpoint in my controller with request body that uses getModelSchemaRef(myObj)

```
 @post('/product-view-configs')
  @response(200, {
    description: 'ProductViewConfig model instance',
    content: { 'application/json': { schema: getModelSchemaRef(ProductViewConfig) } },
  })
  async create(
    @requestBody({
      content: {
        'application/json': {
          schema: getModelSchemaRef(ProductViewConfig,
            {
              title: 'NewProductViewConfig',
            }),
        },
      },
    })
    productViewConfig: ProductViewConfig,
  ): Promise<ProductViewConfig> {

    return this.productViewConfigRepository.create(productViewConfig);
  }
```

and here is my actual question:

**why does the request body look like this?**

[image]

when Really what I expect is an an Object that looks like this in the request body:

```
{
    "_id" : "string",
    "configMetadata" : {
       "name" : "string",
        "description" : "string",
        "createdOn" : "date",
        "lastUpdatedBy" : "date",
        "creatorId" : "string",
        "creatorName" : "string"
    },
    "sharedUsers" : [ 
        {...}
    ],
    "sharedRoles" : [ 
        {...}
    ],
    "tiles" : [ 
        {...}
    ]
}
```

so why don't these properties from baseConfig appear? Could someone please point me in the right direction? I couldn't figure it out from the loopback4 documentation so any help would be greatly appreciated!!

Answer (score 0):

You should use `relations` for associate the models. `hasMany`, `hasOne` etc. topics in the loopback can be usefull for starting research.

https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb4/Relations.html